# Search if jsonb array of string contains value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have arry of strings in a column like :  `["196 2616", "9503744", "36.25260-6027", "2 414 425", "7 034 771 6", "F709714", "1088229", "183144", "505870338", "105075"]`

I want to search if this array contains for example 2 414 425.

I tried something like this:
 `SELECT * FROM  table_name t where t.numbers @> '2 414 425'`
But it doesnt return anything even when it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) needs a proper JSON object on the right hand side:

```
where t.numbers @> '["2 414 425"]'
```

This should work if `numbers` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). Otherwise cast it `numbers::jsonb`

Checking if at least one of multiple keys is contained in the JSON array can be done using the `?|` operator:

```
where t.numbers ?| array['2 414 425', '13261999']
```

The `?&` operator will check if **all** those keys are contained in the JSON array.

Comment: Great that also works, how could I change it so I dont check for single string, but I want to see if jsonb array contains any of multiple values?

Comment: Use the `?|` operator with an array of the keys

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this:

```
select carat_id from table where (numbers)::jsonb ? '13261999';
```